# how to stop handler posted on view - android

Tags: java, android, multithreading

Simply i post a runnable with delay on views using this code:

```
view.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        // Do Something
                    };
                }, delay);
```

I need to stop and remove this runnable sometimes. The idea is that there is delay, sometimes i need to stop it and ignore the delay and everything.

so **how to stop it !?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

calling `view.removeCallbacks(null);`. Passing null as parameter removes every `Runnable` associated with the handler.

Comment: can i check if there is something running as well ?

Comment: no it is not directly possible. What do you need it for ?

Comment: cuz if there is nothing in it to not call it,  well its the solution i wanted, thank you

Comment: I didn't quite get your last comment. Still, you are welcome

Comment: i would check, if there is no handler, do nothing, otherwise stop it

Comment: no it is not possible. However calling `removeCallbacks(null)` doesn't harm you in any case